# How to create line chart with multiple colors

Tags: linechart

How to create a line chart to indicate the on and off states of a component between given set of time periods.I want the charts to be created in java using jfreechart.The sample o/p i need is:

The elements are,
the different electronic components and the green line,red line and orange indicates working, not working and semi working conditions of the component at the given time represented in X axis.

Comment: The image isn't showing

Comment: to upload an image its asking for minimum of 10 reputations and im a new user...

Comment: Apologies! A link to the image would suffice